# SPF verification for email parser system

Tags: email, authentication, exchangewebservices, spf

We are setting up some exchange mailboxes for some automated systems to send alert emails to.  We would like to parse those emails to extract important data related to the alerts.

My job is to write the application that will download the email data using the EWS API and process the data.

Authentication and from-address spoofing prevention are in the conversation and we are looking into SPF Verification.  I understand that senders must publish their SPF DNS records, but what is required on the receiving side?  Is SPF / SenderID verification entirely handled by the Exchange Spam-Filters, or do I need to do manual DNS-lookups in the application itself?  If it is handled by the spam-filters, would messages that fail SPF go into the "Junk Mail" folder, or would they still end up in the "Inbox" folder, but flagged in some way?  Ideally, we do not want the failures to be in the "Inbox" folder since that is the folder I'm downloading the emails from.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPF is handled by the Sender Id Transport Agent in Exchange which has three actions it will take on a SPF fail Reject,Delete and Stamp see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc526541.aspx The stamp action will affect the SCL of a message which depending on how you have that configured https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995744(v=exchg.150).aspx will mean the email message may or may not end up in the Junk Email.

Cheers
Glen